# Boolean variable for attribute required in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to make one input form field required based on one boolean variable in my component.

Component:

```
public myDivHidden: boolean = true;
```

In my html

```
<form #railForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="executeRailForm(railForm.value);" *ngIf="railFormData" ngNativeValidate>
...
<div [hidden]="myDivHidden">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="myName">My Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="myName" [(ngModel)]="railFormData.myName" required="!myDivHidden">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
</form>
```

I am trying to avoid required if div is hidden and make it required if div is visible. I am getting error: `An invalid form control with name='myName' is not focusable.`

How I can make required field required when div is visible and not required when div is invisible in html page?

Comment: Have you tried `[required]="!myDivHidden"`?

Comment: Is `required` defined by you?

Comment: try *ngIf="myDivHidden" it might work in your case

Comment: required="string compare works" but not with boolean.  `[required]="!myDivHidden"` works! nice for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `[attr.required]="!myDivHidden"` or `required="{{!myDivHidden}}"`